# How to convert the csv to lower case using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, lowercase

I wrote the below code to convert a csv to lower case.

```
(Get-Content "$file" -Raw).ToLower() | Out-File "$outfile"
```

But Getting **error** like :

```
Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'.
```

[image: Here is the my error screen shot.]

Comment: What version of PowerShell/Windows are you running? The `-Raw` parameter is introduced in PowerShell 3.0

Comment: thanks Mathias For your response I will use the PowerShell 2.0
Your reply is help full and I solved my error thanks buddy.

[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file).ToLower() | Out-File "$outfile"

Comment: For those who are looking for first case upper and rest lower

`$file="C:\TEST.CSV"
$outfile="c:\out.csv"
Get-Content $file |ForEach-Object { $_.substring(0,1).toupper() + $_.substring(1).tolower()} |Out-File $outfile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Raw` was added in PowerShell 3.0. If you're using 2.0 or below, it doesn't exist. Instead you can do:

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file)
```

Comment: Thanks For Your quick reply Its help full for me and I solved my error.
I write simple
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file).ToLower() | Out-File "$outfile"


Its PowerShell verion problem ...thanks Briantist.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to [briantist's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38401498/712649), pipe the output from `Get-Content` to `ForEach-Object` and call `ToLower()` on each individual line:

```
Get-Content $file |ForEach-Object { $_.ToLower() } |Out-File $outfile
```

Or, in PowerShell 3.0 and up:

```
Get-Content $file |ForEach-Object ToLower |OutFile $outfile
```